# Angular: Dynamically inject services on component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I need to dynamically create and assign service instances to certain objects. All of this happens at run-time, based on user actions.
This is what i would like to achieve, more or less:

**testComponent.ts**

```
@Input() serviceType: any;

// Injector is provide by the upper component
constructor(injector: Injector) {
        super();
        // testComponent knows nothing about fooService (only provided injector does)

        // Could be a string or an object
        this.serviceInstance = injector.get(this.serviceType);

        // It is now able to use a fooService method
        this.serviceInstance.getData().subscribe((data)=>{
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

**fooService.ts**

```
// common method exposed by all services
public getData() { 
   // does something
}
```

Is that the right way to do it?
What if the desired service is not provided anywhere and has to be imported on the fly?

Comment: You can't import on-the-fly. If you use tree-shaking, the code for the service might not event exist in the build output.

Comment: Imagine that my input (serviceType) is a model structured like that: `{ servicePath: string; serviceType: any }`. Would it be possible to load my custom service using SystemJS, then create it and later assign it to my serviceInstance too?

Comment: I guess not. Angular compiles DI stuff to static TS/JS when you build the project. Perhaps with platform-browser-dynamic (without AOT) but I don't know if and how that might work.

Answer (score 1):

This can absolutely be done you just need to register a second provider for the service in the appropriate NgModule like so

```
@NgModule( {
imports: [
],
providers: [
    AppUserApiService,
    { provide: 'AppUserApiService', useExisting: AppUserApiService },
]
}
```